# Getting {"errorMessage": "'httpMethod'", "errorType": "KeyError" while testing Aws Lambda function

Tags: python, json, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I'm creating serverless architecture. In that i trying to open 'index.html' page through api gateway.but while testing Lambda function to POST and GET request. i'm getting error {
"errorMessage": "'httpmethod'",
"errorType": "KeyError",
"requestId": "edaf3570-7804-43ac-a4c8-3e6ea0aa1c40",
"stackTrace": [
"  File "/var/task/lambda_function.py", line 5, in lambda_handler\n    mypage = page_router(event['httpmethod'], event['quaryStringParameters'], event['formbody'])\n"
]
`

```
import json
import os, re, base64
import boto3
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    mypage = page_router(event['httpmethod'], event['quaryStringParameters'], event['formbody'])
    return mypage
    # print("Inside lambda function")
    # print(event)

def page_router(httpmethod, quaryStringParameters, formbody):
    if httpmethod == 'POST':
        htmlFile = open('index.html', 'w')
        htmlContent = htmlFile.write()
        insert_record(formbody)
        return {
        'statusCode': 200, 
        'headers': {"Content-Type":"text/html"},
        'body': htmlContent,
        }
    
    if httpmethod == 'GET':
        # insert_record(formbody)
        htmlFile = open('confirm.html', 'r')
        htmlContent = htmlFile.read()
        return {
        'statusCode': 200, 
        'headers': {"Content-Type":"text/html"},
        'body': htmlContent,
        # 'isBase64Encoded': False
        }

def insert_record(formbody):
    formbody = formbody.replace("=", "' : '")
    formbody = formbody.replace("&", "' , '")
    formbody = "INSERT INTO dynamodb value {'" + formbody +  "'}"

    client = boto3.client('studentinfo')
    client.execute_statement(Statement = formbody)
```

I am trying to insert the data in 'index.html' page through 'POST' method & that data is saved to in Dynamodb. After inserting data into "index.html" through 'post' method and clicking on 'submit' button which is in 'index.html', it opens 'confirm.html' page through 'GET' method.

What is to be done to resolve this &  what should be my json event?

Comment: In your code you are not using `requestId` at all. Where does the error come from?

Answer (score 0):

One of the keys in event (httpmethod, queryStringParameters and formbody), or all af them, is not present.

Do a print(event) at the start of the handler, and see in logs what’s wrong.